# How do you use hook_query_alter to get inside a query's creation?

Tags: 7, database

I'm getting no love from hook_query_alter.  I have a simple query to which I want to add a tag, while also adding a `node_access` tag.  Thus the whole query looks like this:

```
$the_nodes = db_select('node', 'n')
     ->condition('n.type', 'some_node_type')
     ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'))
     ->addTag('node_access')
     ->addTag('my_custom_tag')
     ->execute()->fetchAll();
```

I then define a handler in one of my modules and litter it with debugging statements, hoping something will happen:

```
function mymodule_query_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $the_query) {
    dsm("inside mymodule_query_alter");
    dsm($the_query);
    if ($the_query->hasTag('my_custom_tag')) {
        dsm('Found it!');
        // do real work here
    }
}
```

I then clear the system cache.  Once I've done this, the following things happen:

- My handler is running, and reports a number of invocations from
  various system calls.
- The objects being dumped by the dsm calls are all very much alike --
  they contain only an `alterTags` array, which typically has entries
  for either `node_load_multiple` or `file_load_multiple`, but nothing else -- certainly nothing like a full Query object.
- None of the `alterTags` arrays have an entry for `my_custom_tag`.
- The inner "Found it!" message never fires.

Arggh.  This is my first encounter with `hook_query_alter()`, and I'm probably just missing something basic about its use.  Can anybody clue me in?  (BTW, based on some browsing around, I've also tried defining handlers for `my_module_query_my_custom_tag_alter` and `my_module_query_node_access_alter`, but never see anything from them.)

Comment: Your implementation of hook_query_alter seem correct for me. Are you sure you query is executed?

Comment: Well, there's progress.  I now have `my_module_query_alter()` finding `my_custom_tag`.  If I do `dsm($the_query)`, all I see is the `alterTags` array.  But I'm apparently getting the query object, because I can dump `(string)$theQuery` and see the sql version of the query, and I can do `$the_query->orderBy('n.title')`, and the ordering will happen.  So, yay, I guess.  But shouldn't there be some way for me to see the query object itself, so I can figure out how to make the changes in the query that are the whole point of being here?

Answer (score 0):

Just to close this item out: It appears that my definition of hook_query_alter was, in fact, working correctly.  My problem was in assuming that I would be able to do things like  `dsm($the_query)` and see the components of the query object in preparation for doing stuff with them.  This doesn't seem to be the case -- `dsm()` wasn't returning anything of real use other than `alterTags`, but the `orderby()` (and other similar actions) did in fact alter the query.  So, I'd argue that it's a bit confusing, but works-as-designed, I guess...